# BadZipFile: File name in directory '' and header '' differ

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, unicode, zip

Windows + python 3.5.1

Получаю некий архив 1.zip, в архиве один файл Прайслист_Москва.xlsm, задача извлечь содержимое архива. Выполняю в IDLE:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
zf=ZipFile(r'C:\1.zip')
zf.extractall()
```

получаю ошибку:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Python\question.py",
 line 3, in <module>
 zf.extractall()   File "C:\Python\lib\zipfile.py", line 1347, in extractall
 self.extract(zipinfo, path, pwd)   File "C:\Python\lib\zipfile.py", line 1335, in extract
 return self._extract_member(member, path, pwd)   File "C:\Python\lib\zipfile.py", line 1397, in _extract_member
 with self.open(member, pwd=pwd) as source, \   File "C:\Python\lib\zipfile.py", line 1289, in open
 % (zinfo.orig_filename, fname)) zipfile.BadZipFile: File name in directory 'Åαá⌐ß½¿ßΓ_î«ß¬óá.xlsm' and header b'\xcf\xf0\xe0\xe9\xf1\xeb\xe8\xf1\xf2_\xcc\xee\xf1\xea\xe2\xe0.xlsm'
differ.
```

Если руками извлечь файл и упаковать заново, то все прекрасно работает.

Тот же код из консоли

```
 zipfile.BadZipFile: File name in directory  
 '\xc5\u03b1\xe1\u2310\xdf\xbd\xbf\xdf 
\u0393_\xee\xab\xdf\xac\xf3\xe1.xlsm' and header 
b'\xcf\xf0\xe0\xe9\xf1\xeb\xe8\
xf1\xf2_\xcc\xee\xf1\xea\xe2\xe0.xlsm' differ.
zf.infolist()
[<ZipInfo               filename='\xc5\u03b1\xe1\u2310\xdf\xbd\xbf\xdf\u0393_\xee\xab\xdf\xac\
xf3\xe1.xlsm' compress_type=deflate external_attr=0x20    file_size=3838624 compress_size=3821155>]
c=''.join(zf.namelist())
c       '\xc5\u03b1\xe1\u2310\xdf\xbd\xbf\xdf\u0393_\xee\xab\xdf\xac\xf3\xe1.xlsm'



zf.extract(c,'C:\\')

zipfile.BadZipFile: File name in directory  
'\xc5\u03b1\xe1\u2310\xdf\xbd\xbf\xdf 
\u0393_\xee\xab\xdf\xac\xf3\xe1.xlsm' and header 
b'\xcf\xf0\xe0\xe9\xf1\xeb\xe8\
xf1\xf2_\xcc\xee\xf1\xea\xe2\xe0.xlsm' differ.

zf.extract('\xcf\xf0\xe0\xe9\xf1\xeb\xe8\xf1\xf2_\xcc\xee\xf1\xea\xe2\xe0.xlsm','C:\\')

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python\question.py", line 3, in <module>
zf.extract('\xcf\xf0\xe0\xe9\xf1\xeb\xe8\xf1\xf2_\xcc\xee\xf1\xea\xe2\xe0.xlsm','C:\\')
      File "C:\Python\lib\zipfile.py", line 1330, in extract
member = self.getinfo(member)
  File "C:\Python\lib\zipfile.py", line 1199, in getinfo
'There is no item named %r in the archive' % name)
KeyError: "There is no item named '\xcf\xf0\xe0\xe9\xf1\xeb\xe8\xf1\xf2_\xcc\xee\xf1\xea\xe2\xe0.xlsm' in the archive"
```

Comment: Судя по всему, ошибка возникает из-за несоответствия кодировки имени файла в ZIP-архиве. Я так понимаю, такое случается ([1](http://vostryakov.ru/blog/24-russkie-imena-fajlov-v-zip-arhive-i-python/), [2](https://toster.ru/q/170045)).

Comment: @approximatenumber: редактирование руками модуля из stdlib, чтобы жёстко прописать cp866 вместо cp437 не выглядит как хорошее решение

Comment: @jfs согласен. Я такого и не советовал в качестве решения. Я лишь сослался на ресурсы.

Comment: @approximatenumber: *"Я лишь сослался на ресурсы"* -- я не понимаю, если вы не думаете что ресурсы могут быть полезны для данного вопроса, то зачем на них ссылаться?

Comment: @jfs Я считаю, что данные русскоязычные ресурсы полезны в данном вопросе. Если вы увидели лишь топорный способ устранения проблемы, то я считаю по-другому. В конце концов, на то комментарии и нужны.

Comment: @approximatenumber: ваше право рекомендовать *"топорный способ устранения проблемы"*. Моё право указать что это *"не выглядит как хорошее решение"*

Comment: @jfs согласен, права соблюдены. Просто вы сказали, что я не думаю о полезности ресурсов, что довольно резко. Я лично не нашёл простого способа решения проблемы, потому что у меня она отсутствует, но чужой экспириэнс с объяснением проблемы мне кажется полезным.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, вариант с отключением проверки очень даже работает.

Answer (score 1):

[По спецификации](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT), zip формат понимает только cp437 и utf-8 кодировки. Реализация [`zipfile` модуля в Питоне](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) следует этой спецификации.

> zipfile.BadZipFile: File name in directory 'Åαá⌐ß½¿ßΓ_î«ß¬óá.xlsm' and header b'\xcf\xf0\xe0\xe9\xf1\xeb\xe8\xf1\xf2_\xcc\xee\xf1\xea\xe2\xe0.xlsm'

```
>>> 'Åαá⌐ß½¿ßΓ_î«ß¬óá.xlsm'.encode('cp437').decode('cp866')
'Прайслист_Москва.xlsm'
>>> b'\xcf\xf0\xe0\xe9\xf1\xeb\xe8\xf1\xf2_\xcc\xee\xf1\xea\xe2\xe0.xlsm'.decode('cp1251')
'Прайслист_Москва.xlsm'
```

то есть в одном месте имя было добавлено в архив, используя cp866 кодировку (OEM code page), которая встречается в cmd.exe на русской Винде. В другом месте, имя использует cp1251 кодировку (ANSI code page), которая встречается в байтовых (*A) интерфейсах на русской Windows.

Чтобы исправить проблему, программа, которая создаёт zip-архив, должна использовать utf-8 кодировку (как `7z -mcu` и `zipfile` модуль это делают — хотя документация zipfile не упоминает поддержку utf-8). Например, самый прямолинейный код должен работать как есть:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from zipfile import ZipFile, ZIP_DEFLATED

with ZipFile('pricelist.zip', "w", ZIP_DEFLATED) as archive:
    archive.write('Прайслист_Москва.xlsm')
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь. Дело в том что архив я получаю как есть и могу работать только с тем что дали. Прямолинейное же указание на имя файла, при извлечении, приводит к 'There is no item named %r in the archive' % name... Почитал вышеупомянутые ссылки, подредактировал zipfile.py  # if fname_str != zinfo.orig_filename:
# raise BadZipFile(
# 'File name in directory %r and header %r differ.'
# % (zinfo.orig_filename, fname))    В целом работает, но...

Comment: @Alex: не помещайте информацию существенную для вопроса в комментарии. Обновите ваш вопрос вместо этого. Объясните, что мешает zip-архив в стандартном формате создать (utf-8 кодировку самые популярные zip-архиваторы должны поддерживать). Использование  нестандартной локальной кодировки я могу понять (долгое время zip поддерживал только cp437), но кодировать одно и то же имя, используя разные кодировки в разных местах в архиве, понять сложнее и `BadZipFile` ошибка кажется вполне оправданной. Добавьте в вопрос пример zip-файла: `open('1.zip','rb').read().hex().decode()`